# iCanHaz.js + Moustache doesn't render first row in data object

Tags: javascript, json, icanhaz.js

I have a JSON data object and a text/html javascript template written using the Moustache syntax. I'm using iCanHaz.js as a template parser.

My problem is that the first row in the data object doesn't get displayed.

Here is my JS code:

```
 var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{"data":[{"title":"Title One"}, {"title":"Title Two"}]}');
 var html = ich.data_template(data);
```

And my Moustache template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="data_template">
    {{#data}}
       {{title}}<br />
    {{/data}}   
</script>
```

The above code outputs this as my rendered HTML:

```
<br />
Title Two<br />
```

As you can see "Title One" from the JSON object isn't displayed.

Does anyone know why? I'm taking a guess it's something to do with my JSON object not being structured correctly (arrays/objects).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the raw flag (2nd argument) to true.

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{"data":[{"title":"Title One"}, {"title":"Title Two"}]}');
var html = ich.data_template(data, true); #Note the true.
```

Also, why are you writing your JSON as a string and parsing it?  You can do:

```
var data = {"data": [{"title": "Title One"}, {"title": "Title Two"}]};
var html = ich.data_template(data, true);
```

Without the raw flag, it returns an array of node elements, and you will need to set a root level element for it to work.

```
<script type="text/html" id="data_template">
    <div>
    {{#data}}
       {{title}}<br />
    {{/data}}   
    </div>
</script>
```

You can test this by running the following JavaScript in your console.

```
ich.addTemplate('data_template', '{{#data}}{{title}}<br />{{/data}}');
var data = {"data": [{"title": "Title One"}, {"title": "Title Two"}]};
var html = ich.data_template(data, true);
console.log(html);

html = ich.data_template(data);

console.log(html);

ich.addTemplate('data_template_root', '<div>{{#data}}{{title}}<br />{{/data}}</div>');

html = ich.data_template_root(data, true);
console.log(html);

html = ich.data_template_root(data);

console.log(html);
```

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks - it was the 2nd argument raw flag that I was missing; it now works fine. And re. the raw JSON, I'm actually fetching it from a web service, so above example is just an simplified extraction for the OP. Thanks again.